# Maven-tomcat plugin bootstrap webapp not working

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-tomcat-plugin

Created a simple Webapp using maven:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.kids -DartifactId=kidsMaven -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false
```

My POM file is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.kids</groupId>
  <artifactId>kidsMaven</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>kidsMaven Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>kidsMaven</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```

I wanted to run my this bootstrap webapp on tomcat server using maven plugin. When I am executing

```
mvn tomcat:deploy
```

I am getting following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on
>   project kidsMaven: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection refused:
>   connect -> [Help 1]

I have not installed tomcat externally; instead wants maven to even control my tomcat installation too.

Comment: Do you have a running Tomcat with the manager enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tomcat:deploy` pushes webapp to an existing tomcat deployment. You probably want `tomcat:run`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tomcat6:run` to run the webapp locally.

Answer (score 0):

use mvn tomcat:deploy

and configure your pom with user/password